# Making an edge list from a dictionary that contains another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
  a: {a, b, c},
  b: {a, b, c},
  ...
 }
```

Essentially, a dictionary with keys and values, and the values itself are in another dictionary.

How would I made the keys and values into an edge list

I want each edge to be like:

```
(a, a), (a, b), (a, c), (b, a), (b, b), (b, c)
```

For every key in the dictionary, the edges it's connected to are its values in the dictionary.

Thanks.

Comment: a, b, and c are numbers or what data type?

Comment: you know that in your main `{a, b, c}` is a set?

Comment: The example you have features `set` as values of your keys. Is this correct?

Comment: ok, so then how do do it with a set, because i keep getting errors that says the set is unhashable

Comment: As a list comprehension `my_list = [(key, item) for key, value in x.items() for item in value]`.

Comment: i guess i meant to say set, its not another dictionary.

Comment: I have a question, what do you mean exactly by _and the values itself are in another dictionary._

Comment: I meant to set a set.

Comment: the list comprehension also worked @roganjosh

Comment: @A.Student, I have updated my response which provides two possible solutions which includes when order matters and when not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a, b, c = ('a', 'b', 'c')
main = {a: {a, b, c}, b: {a, b, c}}

output = []

# loop through the keys of the dictionary
for key in main:
    # iterate through set
    for i in main[key]:
        output.append((key, i))

print(output)
>>> [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'b')]
```

Comment: Instead of `value`, you should write `key` since that is what you are actually iterating in `main`.

Comment: @pylang Tku, fixed this

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a dictionary and the value for each key is a set you can try this:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'


x = {
  a: {a, b, c},
  b: {a, b, c},
 }

for key in x:
    for value in x[key]:
        print("(" + key + ", " + value + ")", end=" ")
```

However, the order that you require could not be exactly the same since dictionaries and sets are not sorted data structures. If **order matters**, you can use the following code:

```
a, b, c = 'a', 'b', 'c'

x = {
    a: {a, b, c},
    b: {a, b, c},
 }

y = []

for key in sorted(x):
    for value in sorted(x[key]):
        y.append((key, value))

print(y)
```

I really hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear to me the exact edge cases you are looking for, as an alternative to @double_j's result, you can perform an [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) on the keys and values.

```
import itertools as it

list(it.product(main.keys(), set.union(*main.values())))
# [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'b')]
```

This approach finds the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two iterables: 1) the keys and 2) a set of unique values in the `main` dictionary.